# One to many resultset based on start and end year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to return a resultset that will include the make, model, description, and year for every vehicle based on the following tables. The part I don't understand is returning a row for each year between the start and end years for a given seat.

For example, if a seat runs 2002-2008 I would want to return rows for 2002, 2003, 2004...

**Make:**
MakeId, MakeName

**Model:**
ModelId, MakeId, ModelName

**Seats:**
SeatId, ModelId, StartYear, EndYear, Description

Current single line query as follows:

```sql
SELECT Make.MakeName, Model.ModelName, Seats.StartYear, Seats.EndYear, Seats.Description
FROM Make
INNER JOIN Model ON Make.MakeId = Model.MakeId
INNER JOIN Seats ON Seats.ModelId = Model.ModelId
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you had a table with all of the years, e.g. a _numbers table_ or _tally table_, you could `join` it with the other tables and get a suitable collection of rows. Searching for `[tsql] tally table` should be productive.

Comment: Thanks HABO. While the tally table didn't end up being exactly what I needed, it led me down the path to just populating a temp table with sequential years for each ModelId

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @MIN_YEAR INTEGER = (SELECT MIN(StartYear) FROM [dbo].[Seats]);
DECLARE @MAX_YEAR INTEGER = (SELECT MAX(EndYear) FROM [dbo].[Seats]);

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT @MIN_YEAR AS Year
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Year + 1 FROM CTE
    WHERE Year < @MAX_YEAR
)
SELECT Make.MakeName, Model.ModelName, Seats.StartYear, Seats.EndYear, 
Seats.Description
FROM Make
INNER JOIN Model ON Make.MakeId = Model.MakeId
INNER JOIN Seats ON Seats.ModelId = Model.ModelId
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE Year BETWEEN Seats.StartYear AND Seats.EndYear ) T 
OPTION
(
    MAXRECURSION 0
)
```